# How to show Message when Next button clicked?

Tags: nsis

I created my custom page and want to know, how to check if any of my inputs are empty when I click on Next button. 
The flow is: 
1. Set input values 
2. click next 
3. If empty show "Error, empty. set all the inputs"

I'd tried with nsDialog onChange and onClick but not able to get this

`Function lprConfigServerUserXml`
`nsDialogs::Create 1018`
`Pop $0`
`GetFunctionAddress $0 OnClick`
`nsDialogs::OnClick $0`

`${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 5u 75% 10u "* Server Address "`
`Pop $0`
`${NSD_CreateText} 0 15u 100% 12u ""`
`Pop $SERVER_ADDRESS`
`${NSD_OnChange} $SERVER_ADDRESS setSeverValue`
`${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 35u 75% 10u "* User Name "`
`Pop $0`
`${NSD_CreateText} 0 45u 100% 12u ""`
`Pop $USER_NAME`
`${NSD_OnChange} $USER_NAME setUserValue`
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 65u 75% 10u "* Password "`<br/>`
  Pop $0`<br/>`
  ${NSD_CreateText} 0 75u 100% 12u ""`<br/>`
  Pop $PASSWORD`<br/>`
  ${NSD_OnChange} $PASSWORD setPasswordValue`<br/>`
  nsDialogs::Show`<br/>`
FunctionEnd`

`Function OnClick`
`Pop $0 # HWND`
`MessageBox MB_OK "Error, empty. Set all inputs"`
`FunctionEnd`

No results until now at all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page leave callback function is called when the user clicks the Next button. You can call `Abort` to prevent the user from moving to the next page in that callback.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Custom MyCustomPageCreate MyCustomPageLeave
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Var NameCtrl
Var NameString

Function MyCustomPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Name:"
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u "$NameString"
Pop $NameCtrl
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyCustomPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $NameCtrl $NameString
${If} $NameString == ""
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "You must provide a name!"
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
; TODO: Write $NameString to config file
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!!